# Can't delete child entity without deleting parent entity, regardless of CascadeTypes?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm trying to connect an entity (User) to entities they create which will be Surveys.

I have two repositories, one UserRepository and one SurveyRepository. I can load Surveys according to which User has them and currently they are all mapped by the User_ID, which is a field on the Survey entity.

However, when I try to remove a Survey, this removes my User whenever I define CascadeType.ALL.

But when I don't use that, I get another error "Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:"

I'm gussing this is all related to the password encryption I'm using, but I am not even trying to delete the User entity, I'm just deleting the Survey, which holds a reference, or an ID to the Survey..

I've tried CascadeType.All on both sides, and I've tried not having any CascadeType at all as well.. If I have it on both sides, this deletes the user whenever I tell my surveyRepository.delete(currentSurvey);
And whenever I don't have it on both sides, I get the exception above..

User Entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private Long id;

  @NotEmpty
  @Email
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;
  private String password;

  @NotBlank

  private String username;

  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;

  @NotBlank private String role;




 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Survey> surveys = new HashSet<>();
```

Survey Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")

public class Survey {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "survey_id")
  private Long id;

  private String title, creator, description;
  private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

  @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")

  @OrderBy("position ASC")
  private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
```

I'm just not sure how I can tell JPA/Hibernate not to touch the User whenever we delete the Survey.

It doesn't matter if I save the User with Survvey or not does it?

Basically I've tried a lot of options and I figure I'm not quite grasping the issue, and I suspect it's about the annotations on the User side, but I still feel as if I should be able to delete the child entity with no problem at all since I am not touching the parent entity?

Comment: What is relation between User and Question?

Comment: Also as far as you can avoid using `EAGER` fetch type

Comment: There is none as of now, Survey is the parent to Question. Question doesn't have a Survey variable however, other than that Survey is a parent to Question as you can see above. (And that works fine)

Comment: try using  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: You mean for Survey?
This caused
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`surveydb`.`user_surveys`, CONSTRAINT `FK1ckn4igxg4vnml869o238m1qe` FOREIGN KEY (`surveys_survey_id`) REFERENCES `survey` (`survey_id`))"

"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement" above it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `EAGER` fetch type in `User` class for `surveys`.
You delete survey but because it is existed on `surveys` set in user yet, it wouldn't be deleted actually.
You need to do like this:

```
// User class
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="user")
 private Set<Survey> surveys = new HashSet<>();
```

```
//Survey class
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I guess it's back to the books on this one. I had no idea the FetchType could have usch an impact.. But this can of course cause problems down the road as well can't it? There would be scenarios when Eager is prefered as well right?

Comment: @harrigaturu If eager is necessary then you should remove the child from collection in parent first

Comment: @harrigaturu Would you mind please make my answer resolved, if it is useful and solved the problem?

Comment: I thought this was what I did with surveyRepository.delete(surveyItem);? 

Yes, sorry I'm a noob here.. Hehe

Comment: @harrigaturu survey repository just care about `Survey`. So you need a service class to do removing from collection and so on. Thanks

Comment: So if I want EAGER, I can make a service class is that what you are saying or the other way around? Do you have any example link you can share for me?

Comment: @harrigaturu The important thing is that you remove child from collection in parent then removing itself. You can do it in controller even. But it is not a best practice. So you need a service class to take over deleting child. Sorry I don't have example link for that now